# how to scale background images in V2.77

Tags: interface

I saw a tutorial where someone was able to scale the size of a background image using an older version of blender, but in my version I can't find any way to scale it.

Answer (score 2):

You can scale a background image by using the slider found in the Background Image panel:[image]